# Same Value in the Dynamic jQuery Form

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello to all users of the site, my intent was to create a dynamic form for a multiple association of multiple products to the same customer, and I had the idea to implement it with the help of jquery being able to create a dynamic form, so looking on the internet I came across an example on jsFiddle, which works perfectly. The only thing that I need would be not to have an empty input where you can write but an input that has a fixed value. For example, the word "TEST", and every time a new input is generated, the input generated always has the value = "TEST".
How can I do it?

**Code** (you can copy and paste in your test.html it works!):

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form role="form" action="/wohoo" method="POST">
    <label>impianti</label>
    <div class="CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE-VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE">
        <div class="CLASSE_DEL_DIV">
            <div class="CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE">
                <input type="text" name="impianti[]">
                <input type="text" name="impianti[]">
                <button type="button" class="RIMUOVI_INPUT">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE-VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE').each(function () {
        var $VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE = $('.CLASSE_DEL_DIV', this);
        $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function (e) {
            $('.CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE:first-child', $VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE).clone(true).appendTo($VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE).find('input').val('').focus();
        });
        $('.CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE .RIMUOVI_INPUT', $VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE).click(function () {
            if ($('.CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE', $VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE).length > 1)
                $(this).parent('.CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE').remove();
        });
    });
</script>
```

How to put into.val() `<?php echo $row['impianto_id'] ;?>`

**I have this:**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connessione.php';
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM impianti";
$impianti = mysqli_query($connessione, $query_string);
?>

<h4>IMPIANTO ID CAMPAGNA</h4>
<select name="impianto_id_campagna">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($impianti)) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['impianto_id']; ?>">
            <?php echo $row['concessionaria']; ?>
        </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

I want to echo this in .val()

But it does not work...

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form role="form" action="/wohoo" method="POST">
    <label>impianti</label>
    <div class="CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE-VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE">
        <div class="CLASSE_DEL_DIV">
            <div class="CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE">
                <input type="text" name="impianti[]">
                <input type="text" name="impianti[]">
                <button type="button" class="RIMUOVI_INPUT">Remove</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var impianto_id = '<?php $row[' impianto_id ']; ?> ';
    console.log (impianto_id);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE-VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE').each(function () {var $VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE = $('.CLASSE_DEL_DIV', this);
$(".add-field", $(this)).click(function (e) {
$('.CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE:first-child', $VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE).clone(true).appendTo($VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE).find('input').val(impianto_id).focus();
});
$('.CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE .RIMUOVI_INPUT', $VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE).click(function () {
if ($('.CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE', $VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE).length > 1)
$(this).parent('.CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE').remove();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Karl Hill How to put into.val() <?php echo $row['impianto_id'] ;?>

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using Laravel Blade. You'll need to do something like this for PHP into JS... script type="text/javascript">
    var impianto_id = '<?php $row['impianto_id']; ?>';
    console.log(impianto_id);
</script>

Comment: @KarlHill not work again karl

Comment: @KarlHill i change my original post under "But it does not work...

"

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('.CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE-VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE').each(function() {

var $VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE = $('.CLASSE_DEL_DIV', this);

$(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {

$('.CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE:first-child', $VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE).clone(true).appendTo($VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE).find('input').val('TEST').focus();});// here the test

$('.CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE .RIMUOVI_INPUT', $VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE).click(function() {

if ($('.CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE', $VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE).length > 1)

$(this).parent('.CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE').remove();

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form role="form" action="/wohoo" method="POST">

<label>impianti</label>

<div class="CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE-VARIABILE_DA_INZIALIZZARE">

<div class="CLASSE_DEL_DIV">

<div class="CLASSE_DA_SPECIFICARE">

<input type="text" name="impianti[]">

<input type="text" name="impianti[]">

<button type="button" class="RIMUOVI_INPUT">Remove</button>

</div>

</div>

<button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>

</div>

</form>
```

All you had to do is just add 'test' into the .val() of the input that you created.

Comment: How to put into.val() <?php echo $row['impianto_id'] ;?>